# How does Serotonergic (5-HT2A mediated) Psychedelia work?

Tags: neuroscience, pharmacology

How does serotonergic (5-HT2A specific) psychedelia work? I've read that there are some theories that it might involve the induction of a glutamate release in certain regions of the brain involved in perception.

Answer (score 3):

Brenton, the linked pdf is called "Multiple receptors contribute to the behavioral effects of
indoleamine hallucinogens". It goes into detail on a a few basic behavioral responses.  I don't know what your background is so if you need help understanding parts point them out to me and I'll give it a go.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3110631/pdf/nihms267079.pdf

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0JUrCVOms3MdzdlYmh0SnBmOHc/edit (I'm hosting the pdf on my Google Drive if you aren't able to see the link hosted by the NIH).

Comment: Thanks, mate, if I find the article in question sufficiently helpful I'll accept your answer and up-vote it. I'm grateful that you quoted a reliable source. Of course you can't just take people's word on these Q&A sites without some proof because you can't be certain of their qualifications regardless of what they claim. I probably won't need too much help in understanding it, I usually understand such articles, but if I need help I'll ask.